# Inconsistent accessibility: base class (interface) is less accessible than child class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, interface

I have the following -

```
public interface IAView
{

}

public class BController<TView>
{

}

public interface IAController
{

}
```

I am accessing these classes througn a derived class which is

```
public class D : BController<IAView>, IAController
{

}
```

When I try to compile the program, I get an error saying "base class IAView is less accessible than class D"

Please help. I am working with MVC in Visual Studio Dot Net using C#

Comment: If I copy and paste those definitions into an empty project, it compiles fine. So somewhere, the definitions you've shown and the definitions in your project don't match.

Comment: The code you've posted compiles just fine without that error message. The error message doesn't match the inheritance structure of the code either. Please make a minimal example that when compiled gives the error.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding. Sometimes the compiler maintains old object files from previous builds.

Answer (score 2):

This code compiles

```
public interface IAView
{

}

public class BController<TView>
{

}

public interface IAController
{

}

public class D : BController<IAView>, IAController
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

If you wrap one of the classes with a private modifier - it will give you the error - as

```
private class PrivateClass
{
    public interface IAView
    {

    }
}

public class BController<TView>
{

}

public interface IAController
{

}

public class D : BController<PrivateClass.IAView>, IAController
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```